# Most efficient way to add non-duplicate values in vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector, unique

I have got vector like this

```
vector<Point*> points;
```

I want to add a new points to this vector. However i have got max 50 inside vector points but many of them are duplicates. What is the most efficient way to implement adding non-duplicates values. Till now i did in this way:

```
boolean add_point(vector<Point*> *p, int x, int y){
  for(vector<Point*>::iterator i = p->begin(); i != p->end(); i++){
    if((*i)->x == x && (*i)->y == y)
        return false;
  }
  p->push_back(new Point(x,y));
  return true;
}
```

However when i call that function milion times execution time of my app increase so much.

According to one of stack topic i have tried to do:

```
sort( points.begin(), points.end() );
points.erase( unique( points.begin(), points.end() ), points.end() );
```

However results of both codes are diffrent. Is sort/erase working well on vector of pointers?

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use raw pointers to store heap-allocated memory. Think about using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, or just store the actual struct instead.

Comment: [`std::set<Point>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) would seem seem a reasonable alternative if you require ordering and provide a comparator (which you can also skip if `Point` is synonymous with `std::pair<int,int>`). If ordering is not required, [`std::unordered_set<Point>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) would *potentially* deliver better performance still.

Comment: the name of your class is MyPoint but the name of the operator< arguement it Point, that is causing the error.

Comment: @PorkyBrain nope, i change it - still the same

Comment: i solved problem of overloading operator - i need to implement it ouside of class like @user657267 suggest in his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `Point` struct is something like

```
struct Point { int x, y; }
```

then just store the `Points` themselves in the vector, and provide comparison functions

```
bool operator==(Point const& p1, Point const& p2)
{
  return p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y
}

bool operator<(Point const& p1, Point const& p2)
{
  return p1.x != p2.x ? p1.x < p2.x : p1.y < p2.y;
}
```

after that you can use the following to remove duplicates:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
```

If you want your container to automatically prevent duplicates use a `std::set<Point>` / `std::unordered_set<Point>` (you'll need to provide a specialisation of `std::hash` for the latter), although using a vector with a final sort and remove duplicates may be faster overall. As @PorkyBrain points out you can keep the vector sorted by using `std::lower_bound` when inserting and avoid the final sort.

The most efficient out of all of these depends entirely on your use case, as always write your program using the simplest method first, and profile to see if it needs improving.

Comment: +1 for knowing that vector is usually better than set with POD types. I would suggest using lower_bounds when adding a point (only add if lower bounds not equal to parameter) and add at point of lower bounds iterator, that way the vector stays sorted.

Comment: Isn't `std::set` a better choice? There is no need to manually sort and remove duplicates. Or `std::unordered_set` if the order is no issue?

Comment: @tillaert It depends, cache performance might make the vector version faster than either. But I'd agree to start with either of the sets first (`std::set` would be the simplest code-wise as you don't need to write a hasher) and only change things if profiling shows a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `std::unordered_map`.

The points will be hashed so storage should be faster when checking lots of duplicates.

Comment: `unordered_set` seems like a better option.

Comment: @juanchopanza Do you know any reason of error:  `C2039: 'unordered_set' : is not a member of 'std'` ??

Comment: @user3804906 You need to include the `<unordered_set>` header. Note that this is a C++11 header, so your standard lib implementation must support that.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably faster to put the points directly into the vector. Keeping a sorted vector (by adding using lower_bounds) is usually fastest when dealing with POD types because it is the most cache friendly. Here is an example:

```
void addToSortedVector(std::vector<Point>& v, Point p){
    auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),p);
    if(it == v.end() || !(*it == p)){
        v.emplace(it,std::move(p));
    }
}
```

You can see the speed difference of about 1.5x here: http://ideone.com/E2gqOd however your speed difference will vary depending on cache effects and architecture so take this measurement with a grain of salt.